# Frase já traduzida e voltou a ser inglês

Tags: bug, tradução

Ao ficar durante um tempo no site algumas perguntas recebem novas atividades, com isso aparece uma mensagem. Essa mensagem estava traduzida e agora está aparecendo o termo em inglês novamente.

[image]

**Editado:**

Parece que voltou ao normal agora. O que será que ocorre com as traduções?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]